# Materialize CSS - Transition animation for things other than UL

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, materialize

In the doc, it appears that we can transition UL elements like so:

```
<a href="#!" class="btn" onclick="Materialize.showStaggeredList('#staggered-test')">Click Me</a>

<ul id="staggered-test">
      <li class="" style="transform: translateX(0px); opacity: 1;">
        <h4><a href="#">List Item</a></h4>
        <p>This is a description</p>
      </li>
      <li class="" style="transform: translateX(0px); opacity: 1;">
        <h4><a href="#">List Item</a></h4>
        <p>This is a description</p>
      </li>
</ul>
```

But what I want to transition is a div. I've tried doing this but it doesn't appear to work

```
<a href="#!" class="btn" onclick="Materialize.showStaggeredList('#staggered-test')">Click Me</a>

<div id="staggered-test">
    <p style="transform: translateX(0px); opacity: 0;">
        appear!
    </p>
</div>
```

Comment: I assume you're using the Materialize CSS library? In the docs it only appears to support the list items and image fading.

If it helps, you could manually achieve the effect you're after. Could you give a sample of how you want it to look/behave?

Comment: Essentially what I'm trying to do is this: I have several tabs, and the tabs transition nicely, but the content switches instantaneously when you click on different tabs. So it feels off. Any transition to offset this would work.

Comment: Have you considered using Bootstrap? You can pass a fade parameter to them for this effect?

Failing that, you could set the tab content to opacity: 0, then add an onclick event to the tab triggering opacity: 1 on the content?

To animate the above you could use CSS3 transitions, e.g:

         transition:    all 0.3s ease-in-out;

I hope this helps!

Comment: @Graham :) I've been avoiding using bootstrap over the fancy materialize css

Comment: Fair enough. Can I tempt you with Foundation Zurb instead, perhaps? :)

Answer (score 4):

You only have to create the **div** inside **li**

Regards